Junction Object Sharing/Visibility
I have a custom junction object Objc__c
It has two master detail relationships (ObjA__c and Objb__c)
User U has public/read access via his profile on ObjA__c and has no permission on Objb__c
Both ObjA__c and Objb__c have private sharing model with Grant Access using Role Hierarchy disabled.
When a sys admin creates a record on ObjC__c, this ObjC__c record is still visible to User U eventhough he does not have access to Objb__c.
What is more surprising is that, the link to Objb__c from Objc__c is also visible and the user u is even able to navigate to the Objb__c record via the link though he was not able to perform edit or anything on Objb__c record.
Can someone explain to me how this is possible ?
My assumption was that since this user u does not have any access to Objb__c, the link to Objb__c will not be visible to him in the junction record.
